# DLE исполнение кода в новости

Tags: php, javascript, dle

Суть в общем в чем!? , имеется сайт для новичков 
хочу сделать раздел примеры кода 
движок DLE, хотелось бы сделать каким то образом исполнение кода на типе

```
[php]echo "Hello World";[/php]
```

Во....от а как это реализовать ума не приложу .... 
так же и с `[js][/js]`
на счет безопасности .... все публикации проходят модерацию так что с этим проблем нет

Comment: Нифига не понятно, очень сумбурно и смешанно. Автор, соберитесь мыслью и сделайте нормальный пост так чтобы было четко ясно с чем у вас проблема, что вы попробовали и что не получилось.

Comment: @DanielProtopopov ему нужно, чтобы в контенте статей можно было встраивать php-код который будет выполняться.